# Positivity of Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Given a sequence of real points $a_k$ for $k = 0,\ldots,N-1$ such that $a_{k} = a_{N-k}$ for $k = 0,\ldots,N-1$ (assuming $a_N = a_0$), what conditions on $(a_k)_{k=0}^{N-1}$ would be sufficient for the discrete Fourier transform of this sequence to be positive, i.e.
$$
X_n := \sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n l}{N}\right)a_l \geq 0, \quad n = 1,\ldots,N-1?
$$

Alternatively, say $a_k = f(x_k)$ are sample points of a convex function, would this be sufficient for positivity? I'm not sure how to show this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there are no requirements on the $x_k$, then convexity is certainly not sufficient. For example, consider $f(x)=x$, in which case $a_k=x_k$. It is easy to come up with examples of $x_k$ where $X_n$ are negative. Are you considering $x_k$ that are regularly spaced (i.e. $x_k=m k +b$)?

Comment: @Mark, yes I understand and yes I am considering even spaced sampling points.

Comment: For the continuous transform: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3155.pdf

Comment: I would think you can "upgrade" the continuous transform case to the discrete transform case when $x_k$ are evenly spaced by deriving the discrete Fourier transform from the continuous transform.